Merc (W203) - ABS Light with code c1110
The start of the issues came after replacing the front wheel bearings. At that point i had no abs issues whatsoever. First time around after replacing the wheel bearings and starting up I got ABS codes and error codes i could make sense of and solve: see below.
Some highlight errors (now solved)

C1104 - L6/1 (left front speed sensor): Clean multipole ring and replace if necessary
C1112 - L6/2 (right front speed sensor): Signal fault

Replacing both front abs sensors and the reluctor rings (carefully any without any hammer bashing) solved most of the issues.
Now I’m left with 2 issues, whereof I don’t think I had either when I started.

"C1120 - L6/3 (left rear speed sensor): Line monitoring"
"C1110 - L6/2 (right front speed sensor): Line monitoring"

Both are "current and store" and they also reappear immediately and consistently after erasing error codes. They seem to both consistently appear with 48 & 50 occurrences respectively. I’m not sure what this means. Any info there would be appreciated.
The weird thing to me is this is one of these is the rear and that hadn’t been a problem earlier (I’m sure, and I haven’t touched it since) this has me thinking something else is at stake here, such as perhaps a software issue in the ESP module. Any ideas? Anyone know of relevant reset procedures? It sounds almost as if its something that has been turned on and needs to be turned off.
What’s consistent here is that while doing a rolling test and looking at actual values as displayed from the ESP module while driving around is that both the right-front and rear-left sensors display 0kmph regardless of actual speed.
Also, another side track- are these errors that cause the abs light to be lit? If not- am i chasing ghosts here? Is there something else I should be looking for?
